# Why can't $\sin(x)$ be expressed as an equation in terms of $x$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, triangles

Why can't we write a simple equation where if we give the value of $x$ as input, we get the value of $\sin(x)$ as output?

By simple, I mean an equation involving just addition, division, subtraction and multiplication and exponentiation and keeping it in the realm of real numbers.

And I'm not necessarily asking for an equation, I'm asking if one does not exist, why is it so?

Even an intuitive explanation would work.

(It is my first question here so sorry for not being rigorous enough)

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Please be more specific: What do you mean by a "simple equation"?

Comment: Probably not as "simple" as you'd want it, but this can be done to some degree with [taylor series](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-5-exploring-the-infinite/part-b-taylor-series/session-99-taylors-series-continued/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses99c.pdf)

Comment: "Simple" is in the eye of the beholder.  What do you mean by "simple" here?

Comment: You *can*, quite easily: $f(x)=\sin x$. You are probably referring to formulas that are built using the four basic arithmetic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division) and radicals. If you include exponentiation as an operation and allow complex variables, then $\sin(x)=(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/(2i)$ is such a formula. If you allow taking limits, then of course the Taylor series works as well.

Comment: If you don't allow complex variables or limits, then it is not possible to express $\sin$ in terms of the other types of elementary functions. One explanation of this that can presumably be turned into a proof (perhaps by examining asymptotic behavior) is that formulas built from these types of operations will never be periodic like sine is.

Comment: With simple I was referring to an equation that does not extend infinitely. And I'm not just asking for an equation, I'm asking if it doesn't exist why is it so?

Comment: There is an equation, $f(x)=\sin(x)$. So you should be specific about what you are allowing or not allowing. I presume you are only allowing compositions of rational functions, radicals, and real number exponentiation. Are you looking for a *formal proof* or an *intuitive explanation*? I gave what I consider to be the latter that can be turned into the former.

Answer (score 3):

Because $\sin(x)$ is not an [*algebraic function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function). It is instead a [*transcendental function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function).

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1670527/70305) there is a proof.

Answer (score 0):

It can $sin(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{-(1)^kx^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$, for further information look at [Taylor Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)

Comment: If we would only allow addition, multiplication, division and subtraction, without using complex numbers, why don't we get an equation in that case?

Comment: @John_Nash A rational function cannot be periodic.